# /usr/local/bin/gunicorn Execution Format error in GKE

Tags: python, docker, google-kubernetes-engine, gunicorn

I'm trying to run a gunicorn flask project using GKE. In the GKE container logs, I can see the following errors:

```
{
insertId: "h11nankp4xse43ok"
labels: {4}
logName: "projects/airasia-flightservice-dev/logs/stderr"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-04-19T23:54:29.634907797Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn: exec format error
"
timestamp: "2023-04-19T23:54:19.602419276Z"
```

In the pods, pod status is also "crashedloopbackoff".

Here is my Dockerfile command:

```
#use an existing docker image as a base
FROM python:3.7
#work with directory
WORKDIR /app
#copy all the files in the base file in the app
COPY . /app/
#Download and install a dependency
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
#list down all the contents in the current in current directory in a long format for debugging and inspection purpose
RUN ls -la ./
#only listen to port no 80
EXPOSE 80
#Tell the image what to do when it starts as a container
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-w", "2", "-b", ":80", "main:app", "--preload", "--timeout", "300"]
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: How is gunicorn installed into the image?  Is it part of `requirements.txt`?  If so, can you please show that file.

Comment: Yes. It's installed as part of the requirements.txt

Here is the requirements.txt file:

pyarrow
Flask==2.0.3
Jinja2==3.0.3
Werkzeug==2.0.0
flask_wtf==0.14.3
WTForms==2.2.1
wtforms-html5==0.2.2
xlwt==1.3.0
xlrd==1.2.0
datetime==4.3
Flask-Cloudy==1.1.0
google-cloud-storage
google-cloud-bigquery==2.34.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
openpyxl==3.0.4
pandas==1.0.5
oauthlib==3.0.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1

Comment: @JohnGordon see the above comment.

Comment: It seems quite odd that pip would install an incompatible binary...

Comment: @JohnGordon What should be my next step?

Comment: Are you able to use a different docker base image?

Comment: are u talking about let's say python 3.9 or python latest??? 

Listed dependencies are only compatible with python 3.7. I'm using virtual environments.. any lead?

Comment: ssh into the container and run `file /usr/local/bin/gunicorn`

Comment: How can i do that? I ran ls /usr/local/bin and saw all the binary executable file. Gunicorn is one of them.

Comment: _How can i do that?_ I don't understand what you're asking.  I literally typed out the exact command.  Do you not know how to ssh in to a container?